# Excel Multiple Cells Included in an IF Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I am trying to compare 6 cells, and get a pass or fail at the end, but in Excel it looks like it will only let me have 5 cells. I'm not sure how to word it.

like for example:

```
Pseudocode: if (A1 and B1 and C1 = A100 and B100 and C100 then Pass else Fail)
=if(A1;B1;C1=A100;B100;C100,Pass,Fail)
```

That doesn't work, and Excel says I typed a few errors.

Please can someone help me with this?

**Updated**
Ok, to make this a little more clearer, here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
A1 = 1.0.0.0
B1 = 01/01/2000
C1 = 00:30

A100 = 1.0.0.0
B100 = 01/01/2000
C100 = 00:30
```

Therefore the cell I want the answer will be `Pass`.

But if one of those cells don't match up, then it will be a `Fail`.

Comment: Try using the AND keyword!

Comment: `=IF(AND(A1=A100,B1=B100,C1=C100),"pass","fail")`

Comment: More reading about [AND](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/and-HP005208986.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @nixda, it has worked, but is showing Pass even if the fields are all blank.

Comment: Please edit your post and maybe provide a data sample. It is not clear if the matches are in pairs or if any of A1, B1, C1 should be matched to any of A100, B100, C100. If `all the fields are blank` then, of course the formula will return `pass`. If that is not the result you expect, then you need to explain the input, the logic, and the expected output.

Comment: @teylyn is that any clearer?

Comment: Add a fourth condition to the AND where you check if your first cells (A1,A2,A3) contain a number: `=IF(AND(A1=A3,B1=B3,C1=C3,OR(ISNUMBER(A1),ISNUMBER(B1),ISNUMBER(C1))),"pass","fail")`.That new condition will give you a `false` as soon as there isn't any number in one of your first cells A1,A2,A3. Luckily, in your case, you dont have to check for the other three cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data is a mix of text and numbers, you can check the length of all concatenated cells to see if it's greater than zero:

=IF(AND(A1=A100,B1=B100,C1=C100,LEN(A1&B1&C1)>0),"pass","fail")

Comment: Thank you for answering. I didn't like it that if the cells were empty, that it was failing, so I have blanked the "fail" out - so it would look like this: `...>0),"Pass","")`